# How to call a function in a class under "Solution items" in vb.net / asp project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Bit New to Web Stuff...

I have an asp page, I'm just using the VS created template at this point. I have added a VB.Net class it appears under 'Solution Items' in Visual Studio.  My class name is clsUtil.vb is code is as follows:

```
Public Class clsUtil

Public Function MakeImage(ByVal Text As String) As Object

    '// SET VARIABLE VALUES
    Dim fontDir As String = Server.MapPath(".\")
    Dim fgColor As String = "#000000"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to call the class in-line in the aps as follows:

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>

    <% clsUtil.MakeImage("Testline")  %>

    </div>
```

What I have here doesn't seem to work. I get the error clsUtil is not declared. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if it doesnt belong to a project...its not going to compile...how would you plan to reference it if it doesnt compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the function Public. You won't be able to call a Private function from outside your class. Then you'll either need an *instance* of the `clsUtil` type or mark the function `Shared`.

Finally, a stylistic note you should feel free to ignore if you want: Hungarian notation prefix warts like `cls` are no longer recommended as good programming style. They were important back in the vb6 era when people were more likely to have Option Strict turned off and type information was harder to get from the IDE, but today it tends to make the code less clear rather than more.

Comment: Duh!  Ya I missed that.  Ok I changed to public but still no luck.  It seems the class is out of scope but I'm not sure why.  Re:Style  Old habits die hard :)

Comment: Read the full answer. I listed two different changes you'd need (both in the first paragraph).